# Confused by Django Rest Framework Permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I have a complex set of permissions that I want to apply to my views, but I'm having a hard time understanding where to put them. Here are my basic permissions.

List all projects:

- If the user is the owner and if their account is active
- Or if they are a superuser
- And the object is not private to a different user
- Or they are a member of the assigned group

Problem is that when I add this logic to the permissions classes of the ModelApiViewset, it returns every project. How do I get it to show only the ones that meet the above criteria?

To further illustrate the example, I have 2 accounts right now: my superuser, and a test_user. test_user is not an admin or staff account, and is not part of the manager group. The test_user account is an owner of project 2, but not project 1. But if I use the test_user credentials, I see both project 1 and 2:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Private Project",
        "slug": "test-private-project",
        "description": "Just testing the super private project",
        "group": {
            "name": "manager",
            "id": 1
        },
        "created_date": "2020-04-20T18:04:20.666564Z",
        "modified_date": "2020-04-20T18:04:20.666594Z",
        "owner": {
            "username": "admin",
            "full_name_display": "Administrator",
            "photo": null,
            "is_active": true,
            "id": 1
        },
        "is_private": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test User Project",
        "slug": "test-user-project",
        "description": "Test project for users",
        "group": {
            "name": "Users",
            "id": 2
        },
        "created_date": "2020-04-20T20:10:02.068390Z",
        "modified_date": "2020-04-20T20:10:02.068429Z",
        "owner": {
            "username": "test_user",
            "full_name_display": "Test User",
            "photo": null,
            "is_active": true,
            "id": 2
        },
        "is_private": false
    }
]
```

The test_user shouldn't see project 1 because they are not the owner, not an admin, and the project is private to the admin.

view:

```
class ProjectListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsOwner, IsActive, IsPrivatelyOwned]
```

permissions:

```
class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user


class IsActive(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.is_active


class IsPrivatelyOwned(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if obj.is_private:
            if obj.owner == request.user:
                return True
            return False
        return True
```

I know I'm missing something pretty simple here, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what permissions are. Permissions and filters are 2 different things. Permissions control the right to access objects in your database.

[From the doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples):
Also note that the generic views will only check the object-level permissions for views that retrieve a single model instance. If you require object-level filtering of list views, you'll need to filter the queryset separately. See [the filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) documentation for more details.

Comment: I think you are correct. I was confused by the difference. Thanks for your help.